# AutoFields Plugin for QGIS 3? Or best way to set up Default Values via PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I am working on transitioning my workflow from QGIS 2 to QGIS 3. I was using the AutoFields plugin in QGIS 2 to setup automatic adjustments to the attributes for lines and points (namely their length, lat and lon attributes). It looks like the Autofields plugin is not an option in QGIS 3, so I am wondering if there is a way to setup default values via the Python Console. Here is what I have in QGIS 2:

```
def getAutoFieldsManager():
if not utils.isPluginLoaded('AutoFields'):
    if 'AutoFields' in utils.available_plugins:
        utils.loadPlugin('AutoFields')
        utils.startPlugin('AutoFields')
        af = utils.plugins['AutoFields']
        return af.autoFieldManager
    else:
              return None
utils.loadPlugin('AutoFields')
utils.startPlugin('AutoFields')
af = utils.plugins['AutoFields']
return af.autoFieldManager

afm = getAutoFieldsManager()

for layer in layers:
name=layer.name()
if "Lines" in name:
  
    if afm:
        autoFieldId = afm.createAutoField(  layer=layer, fieldName=u'length', expression=u'$length' )
        autoFieldId = afm.createAutoField(  layer=layer, fieldName=u'startLat', expression=u'$y_at(0)' ) 
        autoFieldId = afm.createAutoField(  layer=layer, fieldName=u'startLon', expression=u'$x_at(0)' )
        autoFieldId = afm.createAutoField(  layer=layer, fieldName=u'endLat', expression=u'$y_at(-1)' ) 
        autoFieldId = afm.createAutoField(  layer=layer, fieldName=u'endLon', expression=u'$x_at(-1)' )
```

Ultimately, I want to setup Default values for Length, start lat/lon and end lat/lon within the python console.

Comment: Please describe what exactly you want to happen, where and when and how.

Comment: Edited the post. Ultimately, I want to setup Default values for Length, start lat/lon and end lat/lon within the python console.

Comment: https://github.com/gacarrillor/AutoFields/issues/5#issuecomment-386892366 Look at [`QgsVectorLayer.setDefaultValueDefinition`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.24/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.setDefaultValueDefinition) and [`QgsDefaultValue`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.24/core/QgsDefaultValue.html)

Answer (score 1):

Original Poster. Thanks @user2856 for calling out QgsDefaultValue and .setDefaultValueDefinition; I didn't know those existed. Below is what ultimately worked for me.

```
myLayers = [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()] 
for layer in myLayers:
name = layer.name()
if 'lines' in name:  
    print (name)
    lengthField = layer.fields().indexFromName( 'length' )
    startXField = layer.fields().indexFromName( 'startX' )
    startYField = layer.fields().indexFromName( 'startY' )
    endXField = layer.fields().indexFromName( 'endX' )
    endYField = layer.fields().indexFromName( 'endY' )
    
    layer.setDefaultValueDefinition(lengthField,QgsDefaultValue('$length',True))
    layer.setDefaultValueDefinition(startXField,QgsDefaultValue('$x_at(0)',True))
    layer.setDefaultValueDefinition(startYField,QgsDefaultValue('$y_at(0)',True))
    layer.setDefaultValueDefinition(endXField,QgsDefaultValue('$x_at(-1)',True))
    layer.setDefaultValueDefinition(endYField,QgsDefaultValue('$y_at(-1)',True))
```